# Google Maps API. Center and zoom

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

```
 $('#map_canvas').gmap().bind('init', function(ev, map) {
        if (myPosition) {
            $('#map_canvas').gmap({ 'center' : myPosition });

            $('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', { 'position':  myPosition, 'bounds': true, 'icon' : '../../css/images/current_location.png'}).click( function () {
                $('#map_canvas').gmap('openInfoWindow', { 'content': 'You are here!' }, this);
            });

            $('#map_canvas').gmap('option', 'zoom', 20);        
        } else {
            $('#map_canvas').gmap('option', 'zoom', 8);
        }

        $.each(markers, function(i, marker) {
            $('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', { 
                'position': new google.maps.LatLng(marker.lat, marker.lng), 
                'bounds': true 
            }).click(function() {
                $('#map_canvas').gmap('openInfoWindow', { 'content': marker.name }, this);
            });
        });     
    });
```

I want to center and zoom to specific position. The result of this piece of code: [http://postimage.org](http://postimage.org/image/v4auwuzwr/)

Comment: what about setZoom() and setCenter() ? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map

Comment: If I use this kind stuff: map.setCenter() or map.setZoom() - same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the latLng of each marker to a LatLngBounds object, then use fitBounds()

[Here](http://www.geocodezip.com/orderby_test_gviz.html) is an example.

Comment: Maybe you can post a quick sample of usage. I don't have any experience using JS Google Map API.

Answer (score 0):

All in all I reached my purpose, but fitBounds() function did some mess to my expectation. My task was: create lot of makers and place them in the map. If I was use fitBounds() function my map zooms out to fit all my markers. Now how does look like my map: [http://postimage.org](http://postimage.org/image/hukrtclup/)